# Populating a large list

Tags: java, list

In production I will have to populate pretty large collection of string (containing about 100M strings). I don't need to iterate through it, just populate and leave it as is.

I will have to persists it, but it's the responsibility of another thread.

I thought it was more efficient to populate `LinkedList` than `ArrayList`.
Here is the simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    Collection<String> col = new ArrayList<>(); // <---HERE
    for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        col.add(String.valueOf(i));
        if (i % 1000000 == 0)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
    long end2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end2 - start2);
    System.out.println(col.hashCode() == System.nanoTime());
}
```

For `ArrayList` the average result is: `61535592462`
But if I replace it with `LinkedList` the program does not even finish. It always stops at `84000000`.

Why that? Could you explain potential cause for these behavior? Is it platform-specific?

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` + `java 8`.

UPD: After pretty long time, the program with LinkedList finshes with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.LinkedList.linkLast(LinkedList.java:142)
    at java.util.LinkedList.add(LinkedList.java:338)
    at com.test.App.main(App.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: LinkedList has more overhead, so it's possible you hit a memory limit.

Comment: @Eran I'm just perplexed. Iterating through ArrayList is faster than through LinkedList. Also populating ArrayList is more efficient as well. What is the use of LinkedList than?

Comment: LinkedList vs. ArrayList: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: Anyway, ArrayList is more efficient for this code, as long as you call ensureCapacity(100000000) or instantiate it with a large capacity, to avoid multiple resizes.

Comment: @user3663882 You do realize that if you're going to persist them, and if you don't need to do any operations on them, it's a really stupid idea to populate them all first and waste memory instead of doing it in batches?

Comment: @Kayaman I cannot do it in batches. We use akka which makes snapshot of the entire currently observable state

Comment: Well that's a different story then.

Comment: @Kayaman Kind of, but I just didn't think it related to the actual problem I was trying to solve. The main issue in my case is performance with which I can populate the list and allow the actor to handle another message.